# Save changes by using "contenteditable" into the html file

Tags: html, contenteditable

Is it possible to save the changes into the html file?

Thank you

Comment: i have only one html file with a bit content. An i want that my colleagues are able to change the content right in there Webbrowser. The changes should not in the local storage of each colleague. Everybody should the same content.

Comment: can't achieve from html you need server-side language like php